# Как заполнить коллекцию Map<K, List<E>>?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, map

Есть список работников `Employee`. Каждый работник прикреплен к конкретному отделу(например: бухгалтер). И у каждого отдела есть руководитель. Мне необходимо составить такую `Map`'у, в которой руководитель был бы ключом, а список его подопечных значением. Что только я не пробовал сделать и как только не старался реализовать, никак не получалось. Как можно это реализовать?

```java
List<Employee> employees = employeeRepository.findAllByIdIn(employeesIds); // Employees

// 
List<Department> allApiActualDepartments = departmentRepository.findAll;

// Ключ: ИД департамента - Значение: ДОК_ИД руководитель
Map<String, String> departmentManagerMap = new HashMap<>();

allApiActualDepartments.forEach(e -> departmentManagerMap.put(e.getId(), e.getDepartmentManagerId())); // Заполнил

Map<Employee, List<Employee>> employeesWithManagers = new HashMap<>(); // Создал ту самую Map'у, осталось запонить

// Я ПЫТАЛСЯ ЗАПОЛНИТЬ Map'у ЧЕРЕЗ ЦИКЛ, НО НИКАК НЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ
for (Employee m : employees) {

// Достал руководителя отдела из БД через репозиторий используя DOC_ID
Employee manager = employeeRepository.findFirstByDocID(departmentManagerMap.get(m.getDepartment().getId()));

}
```

Подскажите варианты реализации.

P.S. В классе `Employee` есть поле `String` `departmentId`(по нему можно узнать, принадлежит ли человек к определенному отделу или нет).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// имитация БД
        List<Employee> SimpleEmployees = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleEmployees.add(new Employee(false));
        SimpleEmployees.add(new Employee(false));
        SimpleEmployees.add(new Employee(false));
        SimpleEmployees.add(new Employee(false));

// имитация БД

        List<Employee> TheBossList = new ArrayList<>();
        TheBossList.add(new Employee(true));


        Map<Employee, List<Employee>> employeesWithManagers
                = new HashMap<>();

// вот тут пройдемся по мапе и положим туда что-то

        for (Map.Entry<Employee, List<Employee>> entry : employeesWithManagers.entrySet()) {
            // получаем к и v если нада сделать дополнительные проверки
            // if k==Employee.isTheBoss(); 
            Employee k = entry.getKey();
            List<Employee> v = entry.getValue();
            employeesWithManagers.put(TheBossList.get(0),
                    SimpleEmployees);
        }

       // или же через стримы 
       employeesWithManagers.forEach((k,v) ->
            employeesWithManagers.put(TheBossList.get(0),
                    SimpleEmployees));


    }
}
```

Comment: Вы берете Босса под индексом 0 - каждый раз. И ведь получается чо добавляться будет один и тот же босс на кажого работника.

Comment: @ArturVartanyan я не приводил пример того как бы я связал значения на уровни персистентности, дело было в том как пройтись по мапе и что то сделать

Comment: @ArturVartanyan если вам нужно узнать как правильно джойнить таблицы, что бы получить ожидаемый результат, тогда вопрос будет совсем другой